# How can I make my navigation bar take up full width and stay at the very top of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I created a navigation bar for my ASP.NET page. I put it on my site.master page. I want to increase the width of the navigation bar so that it is all the way to the end of the screen. Right now, the navigation bar is very short and it only covers half of the screen,

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="RMAPTrusted.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
     <link href="Content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
  <link href="Content/new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
        <form runat="server">
      <nav class="navbar">
      <label class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle" for="chkToggle">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </label>
      <a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkToggle" />
      <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  
    </nav>

  

        <div>
  
  </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the image

[image]

and below is the stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        height: 70px;
        align-items: center;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
    }
```

I tried to increase the min-width to 100%. when I do that then the bar moves down and there is a space between the navigation bar and the top. Below is the image

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're going to have to add the content at the placeholders (as if the server already sent it there). Without that content the navbar is at the very top.

Comment: How about setting the class navbar's width to 100% first before setting the min-width?

Comment: Yes, this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add The Position And Top Property In CSS

```
  #randomdiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
  }
```

Comment: I tried adding the position and top css in the navbar and the navigator bar became very small. I pasted the image in the original post at the bottom including the css.

Comment: Then Can't Tell Whats Wrong